# How to access rendered DOM Objects by Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I just started learning protractor and having issues getting the text from DOM object.

Below is the div from **AngularJS** application

```
"<div class="input-group application-item-field">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="symbol" ng-model="ctrl.getApplication().company.symbol">

                </div>"
```

I am trying to get the text of symbol object but it is not shown in span.

I tried

```
element(By.model('ctrl.getApplication().company.symbol')).getAttribute('class').then(function(text){
                        console.log(text);


                    });
```

But it didn't return the text.

I can get the value of text by using `console.log(document.getElementById('symbol').value);` on developer tools.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to always use Angular-specific locators. `by.id` would be a perfect choice here:

```
var symbol = element(By.id('symbol'));
```

To get the input value, use [`.getAttribute()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute):

```
symbol.getAttribute("value").then(function (value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

If you want to see the model value, you can use [`.evaluate()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate):

```
symbol.evaluate("ctrl.getApplication().company.symbol").then(function (modelValue) { 
    console.log(modelValue);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Alecxe. It worked for me. Thanks for suggestion of using by.id

Comment: I accidentally clicked on icon. Your answer worked for me.

Comment: how to access custom dom object. let say  : <watchlist _ngcontent-gws-12="" id="ui-id-26" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block; width: 468px; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 357px;">